# Представить list в функцию

Tags: python

У меня есть список, например [10, 0, 2, 6, -1] который обозначает функцию: lambda x: x  4 + 2 * x  2 + 6 * x - 1
Есть ли какая то библиотека, или функция с помощью которой можно любой подобный список представить в виде такой функции? То есть ты в функцию передаёшь list а возращается функция

Comment: А где в функции 10? Что означает "возвращается функция"? В каком виде она возвращается?

Comment: в функцию  аргументом передаётся список а возращается функция

Comment: Это те же самые слова, что и в вопросе. Поэтому я повторю свой вопрос такими же словами: "где в функции 10? Что означает "возвращается функция"? В каком виде она возвращается?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def factory(koefs):
    return lambda x: sum(a*x**n for (n, a) in enumerate(reversed(koefs)))

# Примеры работы:

# 3x**2 + 5
koefs = [3, 0, 5]
func = factory(koefs)
print(func(-1))  # 8
print(func(2))   # 17

# x**3 + x
koefs = [1, 0, 1, 0]
func = factory(koefs)
print(func(-1))  # -2
print(func(2))   # 10
```

Comment: Тут возвращается значение f(x). А нужно, чтобы "возвращалась функция", х.з. что это означает.

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду

Comment: @Егор, если ответ вам помог, то вы можете отметить его как решение (галочка слева от вопроса) или оценить его (стрелка сверху от цифры слева).

Comment: @Эникейщик, не совсем так. factory возвращает именно функцию. А уже потом в эту функцию можно подставить x и получить значение.